# Node.js aws s3 sdk v3 showing error while putting object

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, graphql

I am uploading file to s3 from node.js graphql api using graphql-upload,

```
                const { createReadStream, mimetype, filename } = file;
                const fileStream = createReadStream();
                const prefix = encodeURIComponent(folder) + '/';
                const uploadParam = {
                    Bucket: bucket,
                    Key: `testing`,
                    Body: fileStream,
                    ContentType: mimetype,
                };
                await s3.send(new PutObjectCommand(uploadParam));
```

Every time I upload, it show this error

```
  NotImplemented: A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented
  Code: 'NotImplemented',
  Header: 'Transfer-Encoding',
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could fix this by converting the fileStream to a string.

Answer (score 1):

Root cause of the problem is missing `ContentLength`. New version of `@aws-sdk/client-s3` cannot find out file size by `graphql-upload`'s stream alone. Possible solutions:

1. pass file size from frontend separately and then specify `ContentLength` at `PutObjectCommand`
2. use [@aws-sdk/lib-storage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_lib_storage.html) if you don't know file size at the time of `s3Client.send` call

Comment: using lib-storage fixed it for me, thanks